# Setting up functions within structs

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am having trouble understanding how to setup my functions within structs, this may have been covered before but in a slightly different way.
Consider the code below written in C++,

```
//Struct containing useful functions.
typedef struct Instructions{
    void W(float);
    void X(float); 
    void Y(float); 
    void Z(int); 
}instruct;
```

I have started but defining my struct with these void functions, however i wish to define what each function does in the program lets say,

```
void Z(int x){
    do something...       
}
```

Both the struct and the function were defined in the global. My question is would i have to refer to the function(in this case void Z(int x)) as:

```
void instruct.Z(int x){
    do something...
}
```

or as i have previously done? Furthermore if there better ways of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Do you really want to use C as the tag says?

Comment: Do not use C tag for C++ questions. These are different languages.

Comment: This is really basic C++ syntax and should be covered by any good book or tutorial. You might want to start there.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use member functions

```
//Struct containing useful functions.
typedef struct Instructions{
    void W(float);
    void X(float); 
    void Y(float); 
    void Z(int); 
}instruct;

void instruct::Z(int x){ // use :: instead of .
    //do something...
}
```

or pointer-to-functions

```
//Struct containing useful functions.
typedef struct Instructions{
    void (*W)(float);
    void (*X)(float); 
    void (*Y)(float); 
    void (*Z)(int); 
}instruct;

void Z1(int x){
    //do something...
}

// in some function definition
instruct ins;
ins.Z = Z1;
```

Comment: There's really no need for that `typedef` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your second solution seems intriguing. For that would i then pass an integer(lets say int a= 5;) to Z1 by saying(in your case) ins.Z(a)?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Instructions{
    void W(float);
    void X(float); 
    void Y(float); 
    void Z(int); 
}instruct;

void instruct::Z(int x){
    do something...
```

}

this is how you have to refer if I understood your question correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Based on MikeCAT answer, `std::function` could be used to be more "modern".
Note this requires a `C++11` compiler.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/YswqcR)

```
#include <functional>

struct Instructions
{
    std::function<void (float)> W;
    std::function<void (float)> X;
    std::function<void (float)> Y;
    std::function<void (int)> Z;
};

void Z1(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
    Instructions ins;
    ins.Z = Z1;

    return 0;
}
```